# Is there a DFA that accepts no string, but has at least one final state?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Is there a DFA that accepts no string, but has at least one final state?

I think it would be possible to make a DFA that accepts no string only by creating no final states or by making sure that the final states are not accessible. But how can a state not be accessible if a DFA has all of its transitions defined?

Comment: It is certainly possible, and I challenge you to find an example. Be creative.

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/65180/755

Answer (score 2):

Consider a 2-state DFA over the alphabet $\{a\}$ (single character alphabet) that accepts only the empty string:

[image: only empty string accepted]

In this DFA, state `0` is the start state, and also the only accepting state. Now, if state `1` were the start state (but state `0` still the only accepting state), what strings would this machine accept?